# currency converter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make currency converter.  I have 2 inputs and 2 currencies. Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td> want to buy <input id="firstinput" onkeyup="convert('C')"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="from">
                    <option value="GEL" selected>EURO(EUR)</option>
                    <option value="USD">USdollar(USD)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> want to buy <input id="secondinput" onkeyup="convert('F')"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="to">
                    <option value="EUR">EUR0(EUR)</option>
                    <option value="USD" selected>USdollar(USD)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

When the first selection is EUR and the second is USD, it should multiply by some value (say 2).  When the first selection is USD and the second EUR, then divide by 2.  Otherwise multiply by 1.

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: Please post the code to the function `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your HTML:
I made some changes for consistency. Please check carefully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td> want to buy <input id="firstinput" onkeyup="convert('C');"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="from" onchange="convert('C')">
                    <option value="EUR" selected>EURO(EUR)</option>
                    <option value="USD">USdollar(USD)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> want to buy <input id="secondinput" onkeyup="convert('F')"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="to"  onchange="convert('F')">
                    <option value="EUR">EURO(EUR)</option>
                    <option value="USD" selected>USdollar(USD)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is your javascript code:

```
function convert(param1){
    var factor;
    f = document.getElementById('from').value
    t = document.getElementById('to').value

    if(f == t){
        factor = 1
    }
    else if(f == 'EUR' && t == 'USD'){
        factor = 1.06;
    }
    else if(f == 'USD' && t == 'EUR'){
        factor = 1/1.06;
    }

    if(param1 == "C"){
        document.getElementById('secondinput').value = document.getElementById('firstinput').value * factor
    }
    if(param1 == "F"){
        document.getElementById('firstinput').value = document.getElementById('secondinput').value * factor
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery Ajax.....

```
$('#result').val('Loading...');

var amount = $('#amount').val();
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();



 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
       url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=" + from + "_" + to +"&compact=y",
    success: function(data) {
        var exchangeRate = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

        var result = amount*exchangeRate;
           $('#result').val(parseFloat(result).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's free service or paid?